# Newly created users are suspended by default and require web login

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk

My application creates a new user and needs to manage events in user's calendar immediately.

```
user = directory.users().insert(body=new_user).execute()

{
    ...
    'primaryEmail': 'email@domain.com',
    'suspended': True,
    'suspensionReason': 'WEB_LOGIN_REQUIRED'
}
```

But calendar is not available, until user log-in via web.

```
calendar.calendars().get(calendarId='email@domain.com').execute()

{
    "error": {
        "message": "Not Found",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Not Found",
                "reason": "notFound",
                "domain": "global"
            }
        ],
        "code": 404
    }
}
```

So my questions are:

- Can i activate user via API without his WEB login?
- Can i create or activate user's calendar via API directly?

Thanks for the answers and suggestion in advance!

Comment: When you create a user, user should not be suspended. I tired the above scenario, and I am able to access users calendar using calendar api(I am the admin of the domain). Also, when creating domain you should set calendar settings in such a way that, it should share all the calendar information. check this information "WEB_LOGIN_REQUIRED: A new account is automatically suspended by Google until the initial administrator login which activates the account. After the account is activated, the account is no longer suspended."

Comment: @SGC i am also domain's admin. Can you share how do you access calendar?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this will be possible as these users will not have accepted the Google ToS yet and you cannot accept these via any API I'm aware of.

This property name, `agreedToTerms`, is a boolean that can be pulled with the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users) but it cannot be written to.